# Dynamically setting display to none does not work

Tags: javascript, css, setinterval, display

I have a language select menu, which I want to be initially hidden, when a user clicks 'ENG' link, it should gradually appear. When a user clicks it again, menu should disappear. However, for some reason my setting class with 'display: none;' does not work... I also tried to set it directly through js: `elem.style.display = "none"`

My html:

```
<div class="header__lang-container _flex-column-center nav__item-container">
                <a href="" class="nav__simple-link header__lang _is-active-simple-link">eng</a>
                <ul class="lang-container _hidden">
                    <li><a href="" class="lang-container__eng lang-container__item">eng</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="lang-container__ukr lang-container__item">ukr</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

My js:

```
    const lang_switcher = document.querySelector('.header__lang');
const lang_container = document.querySelector('.lang-container');
let isSwitcherOpen = false;
lang_switcher.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let opacity_value = 0;
    const atomic_value = 0.04;
    lang_switcher.classList.toggle('_is-active-simple-link');
    lang_container.classList.toggle('_hidden');
    if(!isSwitcherOpen) {
        lang_container.style.display = "block";
        const interval_id = setInterval(() => {
                if(opacity_value < 1) {
                    lang_container.style.opacity = opacity_value.toString();
                    opacity_value += atomic_value;
                }
                else {
                    clearInterval(interval_id);
                }
        }, 10);
    }
    isSwitcherOpen = !isSwitcherOpen;
});
```

_hidden class:

```
._hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `lang_container.style.display = "block";` because it collides with `lang_container.classList.toggle('_hidden');`

```js
const lang_switcher = document.querySelector('.header__lang');
const lang_container = document.querySelector('.lang-container');
let isSwitcherOpen = false;
lang_switcher.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let opacity_value = 0;
  const atomic_value = 0.04;
  lang_switcher.classList.toggle('_is-active-simple-link');
  lang_container.classList.toggle('_hidden');
  if (!isSwitcherOpen) {
    const interval_id = setInterval(() => {
      if (opacity_value < 1) {
        lang_container.style.opacity = opacity_value.toString();
        opacity_value += atomic_value;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval_id);
      }
    }, 10);
  }
  isSwitcherOpen = !isSwitcherOpen;
});
```

```css
._hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__lang-container _flex-column-center nav__item-container">
  <a href="" class="nav__simple-link header__lang _is-active-simple-link">eng</a>
  <ul class="lang-container _hidden">
    <li><a href="" class="lang-container__eng lang-container__item">eng</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="lang-container__ukr lang-container__item">ukr</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this line: `lang_container.style.display = "block";`

There's no need to set the display directly on the element since we are already toggling the _hidden class.